# python 3.3.3 hangs if opened in shell within emacs

Tags: python-3.3, emacs24

I am trying to start python 3.3.3 within a shell buffer in emacs (GNU emacs 24.2). OS is Win7. If I start python from the regular command line, the program works well. If I open a shell buffer in emacs (M-x shell) and type "python" into the command line (the program is in the path), it prints "python" on a new line and stops there.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. Try a workaround: load python-mode first, then open the shell interactively. This will provide some setup, which might cure it.

With shipped python.el <kbd>M-x run-python RET</kbd>

With python-mode.el <kbd>M-x python[VERSION] RET</kbd>

VERSION is optional, it provides non-default shells without re-customizing the variable holding the command-name, i.e. py-shell-name

Comment: Thanks. python-mode runs well. No probs there. Only when I try to run python from command line in an emacs shell buffer it does not work. After running python-mode, the problem persists.

Comment: @roschu Having a look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode it seems your problem is not reported. So you may try python-mode.el

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I do not really know what solved the problem, but aynway: it is working again.